# What is the difference between database/sql connection & pgx pool on golang?

Tags: postgresql, go, pgx, ent

I'm trying to use [ent](https://entgo.io/) on golang backed with postgresql DB.

Current legacy code uses [pgxpool](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx/v4/pgxpool) for connection pool. But `ent` does not support pgx pool, and only support standard connection pool of `database/sql`.

What is difference between two? Is it ok to use standard connection pool with PostgreSQL database? or should I use pgx pool for this?

Comment: It would be interseting to know the performance differences between the two, since using pgx directly seems to require context

Answer (score 0):

tl/dr;

- database/sql - is an interface to access any database engines
- pgx - is one of postgres driver (pq is a postgres driver too)
- pgxpool - is a part of pgx which can work with connection pools of postgres

database/sql can be initialized to work with pgx driver for postgres. `db, err := sql.Open("pgx", databaseDsn)`

> Is it ok to use standard connection pool with PostgreSQL database? or
> should I use pgx pool for this?

it depends of your needs